# How to set the background color of breakpoints in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In VS2010, breakpoints were highlighted with a background color:

[image]

In VS2012, the setting is still there but it has no effect; the breakpoints look like this:

[image]

Is it like this for everyone, or just me? Can I have the background color back somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should just work out of the box. The color that is used for the breakpoint is set in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors under the display item "Breakpoint (Enabled)".

If that looks like it's set correctly but you're still not getting the right behavior, check if you have any extensions which might be overriding the setting.

Comment: I have the same problem, though mine was displaying as per the top image for a long time and has somehow switched to the bottom image in the last few days.  Further, the "Breakpoint (Enabled)" setting is not shown, I only have the "Breakpoint - Advanced" settings.  I have "repair installed" VS2012 Update 2 to no avail.  Will update if i find it.

Comment: Result was "devenv /resetuserdata" did the trick - but obviously lost a bunch of settings on the way.  Luckily I exported then first, and re-imported them after.  I've no idea what actually went wrong.